# how to disable button when it reaches 20 clicks, how to reset the input after every click

Tags: javascript, html

I am new at JS, I work on a game from a tutorial and I want to add these 2 things.
The game is guess the number game. I would like the Input to reset after every click on the button so the user won't have to delete the number manually. The game gives you 20 tries. when you reach 20 I would like the button to be disabled and the scrore field to be at 0.
I looked on suggestions online but nothing worked for me.

html:

```
<header>
      <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
      <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
      <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
      <div class="number">?</div>
</header>
<main>
      <section class="left">
        <input type="number" class="guess" />
        <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
      </section>
      <section class="right">
        <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
        <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
        <p class="label-highscore">
           Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
        </p>
      </section>
</main>
```

JS:

```
const randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
let number = document.querySelector('.number');
const checkButton = document.querySelector('.check');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
let score = document.querySelector('.score');
let currentNumber = 20;
const againButton = document.querySelector('.again');

checkButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let inputNumber = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
  if (!inputNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'No number was picked!';
  } else if (inputNumber > randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too high';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber < randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too low';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber === randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Correct!';
    number.textContent = randomNumber;
    document.body.style.background = 'green';
  }
});

let guess = document.querySelector('.guess');
guess.value = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
let number = document.querySelector('.number');
const checkButton = document.querySelector('.check');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const input = document.querySelector('.guess');
let score = document.querySelector('.score');
let currentNumber = 20;
const againButton = document.querySelector('.again');

checkButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    
  let inputNumber = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
  if(currentNumber === 1){
  checkButton.disabled = true;
  }
  if (!inputNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'No number was picked!';
  } else if (inputNumber > randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too high';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber < randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too low';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber === randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Correct!';
    number.textContent = randomNumber;
    document.body.style.background = 'green';
  }
  input. Value = "";
});

let guess = document.querySelector('.guess');
guess. Value = null;
```

Comment: find it here 
https://jsfiddle.net/h87wvpa5/1/

Answer (score 0):

it's working now :

```js
let number = document.querySelector('.number');
const checkButton = document.querySelector('.check');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
let score = document.querySelector('.score');
let currentNumber = 20;
const againButton = document.querySelector('.again');
const inputSelector = document.querySelector('.guess');
function clickFunctionHandler(){
if(currentNumber==0){
this.disabled=true;
return;
}
const randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
document.body.style.background = '';
  let inputNumber = inputSelector.valueAsNumber;
  if (!inputNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'No number was picked!';
  } else if (inputNumber > randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too high';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber < randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Too low';
    currentNumber--;
    score.textContent = currentNumber;
  } else if (inputNumber === randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'Correct!';
    number.textContent = randomNumber;
    document.body.style.background = 'green';
  }
  inputSelector.value='';
}
checkButton.addEventListener('click',clickFunctionHandler);

againButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
currentNumber = 20;
score.textContent = currentNumber;
checkButton.disabled=false;
})
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
      <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
      <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
      <div class="number">?</div>
</header>
<main>
      <section class="left">
        <input type="number" class="guess" />
        <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
      </section>
      <section class="right">
        <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
        <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
        <p class="label-highscore">
           Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
        </p>
      </section>
</main>
```